# Django form post request without rendering

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have django form, then for each field I set initial value. How can I make `POST` request in my `view.py` (like after pressing submit button) without rendering the form. I just need to send these initial values as POST request to another url.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the form in HTML and set `display:none` is style attributee of each field. It will hide the form from front-end and when you click on submit button it will send all data in POST request.

```
<form method='post'>
    <input name='field_name' style='display:none' value='abc'>
    <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

Above code will show only submit button on front-end and by clicking on it, it will send value of input field in POST request.